# config Squid for allow user working between monday to saturday 08.00 AM to 08.00 PM

Tags: squid

Could you please let me know about config on Squid for allow user access internet between monday to saturday time : 08.00 AM - 08.00 PM
about config below is currect or not.

```
####################################################
acl home_network src 192.168.1.100
acl business_hours time M T W H F S 9:00-17:00

http_access allow home_network business_hours
http_access deny

###################################################
```

About time : `M T W H F`  means Monday to Friday right?
And how to fix for Saturday and Sunday? Is it `S` = Saturday or Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

The days of the week are defined with letters, to be used as follows:

```
S - Sunday
M - Monday
T - Tuesday
W - Wednesday
H - Thursday
F - Friday
A - Saturday
```

When the first letter is ambiguous, the second letter is used.

Source: [Access Control and Access Control Operators - Squid User Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20161207135951/http://www.deckle.co.uk/squid-users-guide/squid-access-control-and-access-control-operators.html)